# How to set mapview to not show my current location?

Tags: android, android-mapview

how to coding to set mapview don't show the current location

now it's not show on emulater but when I try to install on my mobile , the current location sigh will show

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getCoordinateE6(double coordinate) {
    return (int) (coordinate * 1E6);
}

GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(
    GoogleMapServiceHelper.getCoordinateE6(latitude),
    GoogleMapServiceHelper.getCoordinateE6(longitude));
getMapView().getController().animateTo(geoPoint);
```